# Is type inference based off the shape of an object possible in typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, duck-typing

Lets say I have 3 Interfaces:

```
interface Animal {
  height: number
  name: string
}

interface Dog extends Animal {
  numberOfTeeth: number
  hasTail: boolean
}

interface Cat extends Animal {
  sizeOfPaw: number
}
```

and lets say I query an api like this:

```
function getAnimal(id:string, animalType:string) : Animal {
  const res = await (axios.get(`http://animalapi.com/${animalType}/${id}`));
  return res.data; // Could be a cat, could be a dog, based on animal type
}
```

If I try to do:

```
const animal:Dog = getAnimal("1", "dog"); // Would it be possible to not need to pass the string dog? Perhaps store the "dog" value within the interface and pass it from there?
```

I get errors that 'Animal is missing the following types', followed by the types that are in Dog.

Is it possible to be able to obtain both Dog and Cat from the same function, without having to duplicate the call?

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/ND2g8W) maybe?  I'm not sure why your implementation seems to return a promise instead of an actual value, or what to do with third-party dependencies like `axios`, so I'm just ignoring that.  You've also written what looks like a second question in a code comment. Question posts in SO should have ask a single primary question, so if you want that answered you might want to make a separate post for it (but the short answer is no, the type system is erased, so if JS code needs `"dog"` then you need to pass `"dog"` directly; there is no interface at runtime).

Comment: Oh, and is `id` and `number` or a `string`? Could you [edit] to clear that up?  Anyway, if [this](https://tsplay.dev/ND2g8W) meets your needs I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Apologies for the poor formatting of the question. The use of axios is because I am querying an external api that has a few endpoints, but many of the data structures it returns contain duplicated values. Is this declare syntax still possible for such a function?

Comment: The `declare` syntax is just to show the typing.  You'd presumably want to actually implement it, but this isn't a question about axios, right?  Or about promises vs synchronous?  So you could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/m0n7xw) or [this](https://tsplay.dev/wEBggN) or any number of things, but it seems out of scope for the question.  The real question is about the typing from input `"dog"` or `"cat"` to output `Dog` or `Cat`, right?  How would you like me to proceed with answering this question?

Comment: I believe the ProductionMap solution solves my problem, thank you!

Comment: `ProductionMap`?  I'm confused here.  Edit... you mean `AnimalMap`?  Okay.  Could you [edit] to show that you're returning a `Promise<Animal>` and not an `Animal`?  Just make sure the only problem with your example code is the typing.  You're `await`ing inside the implementation but it's not an `async` function and then you're returning something that is not a `Promise` I guess but it really must be... etc etc

Comment: In the accepted answer, you have to call `const dog = getAnimal("1", "dog")` and then after that write `if (isDog(dog)) {...}` before you could treat `dog` as a `Dog`.  And it looks like it requires you to add a `type` property to your returned data to even do that.  Can you explain why that answers the question as asked?  Isn't the `AnimalMap` version what you were asking for?  Help me out here. I love not having to write up answers, but I don't see the existing answer as actually addressing the question directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is type inference based off the shape of an object possible in typescript?

Yup, this is called type narrowing, and you can do it with a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) that joins the `Dog` and `Cat` shapes but gives each shape a unique "tag" that distinguishes it from the others (this might be a property like `id`, `type`, or whatever you want to call it):

```
interface AnimalBase {
  height: number
  name: string
}

interface Dog extends AnimalBase {
  type: 'dog';
  numberOfTeeth: number
  hasTail: boolean
}

interface Cat extends AnimalBase {
  type: 'cat';
  sizeOfPaw: number
}

type Animal = Dog | Cat;
```

Now, when you go to create an `Animal`, TypeScript will expect you to identify the specific shape by specifying the `type` property. Then you can pass along `animal.type` wherever you want since it's a string literal:

```
const dog: Animal = {
  type: 'dog',
  numberOfTeeth: 100,
  hasTail: true,
  height: 100,
  name: 'Roofus'
};

getAnimal("1", animal.type)
```

This pattern has the added benefit of allowing you to narrow a generic `Animal` type to a specific sub-type. For example, you can use it to write a type predicate to check if an animal is of a particular constituent type:

```
const isDog = (animal: Animal): animal is Dog => {
  return animal.type === 'dog';
}

const dog: Animal = {
  type: 'dog',
  numberOfTeeth: 100,
  hasTail: true,
  height: 100,
  name: 'Roofus'
};

// here, TypeScript knows that animal is now of type Dog
if (isDog(dog)) {
  // myAnimal shape is now Dog
}
```

Without discriminated unions, you'd need to do a type assertion and check a property that you know is absolutely unique to dogs (maybe `hasTail`, but that's true for cats too):

```
const isDog = (animal: Animal): animal is Dog => {
  return typeof (animal as Dog).numberOfTeeth !== 'undefined';
}
```